# Count a tag that has a specific class

Tags: php

Please help
I want to loop between these tags div ..

```
<p> answer 1 </p>   
<div class='right'>Obama</div>
<p> answer 2 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Brazil</div>
<p> answer 3 </p>
 <div class='right'>Tennis</div>
<p> answer 4 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Sand</div>
<p> answer 5 </p>
 <div class='right'>Nike</div>
```

and count the tag div that has the class 'right'..and echo the sum of these tags, in this exemple the sum is 3.

Comment: you'll need to start coding, you can start by using [`DOMDocument`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for parsing HTML using PHP

Comment: an unorthodox way... `echo substr_count($html, "<div class='right'>"); // 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in many ways.

1. Create a regex to search HTML code
2. Loop using strpos to find a specific string (Not great if there are spaces)
3. Use a third party application like `simple_html_dom` to fetch the elements most accurately (My favorite).

I'll just quickly show you how to do #3.

## Finding element count using SimpleHTMLDom

```
$str = "<p> answer 1 </p>   
<div class='right'>Obama</div>
<p> answer 2 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Brazil</div>
<p> answer 3 </p>
 <div class='right'>Tennis</div>
<p> answer 4 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Sand</div>
<p> answer 5 </p>
 <div class='right'>Nike</div>";

$html = str_get_html($str);
echo count($html->find("div[class='right']"));
```

Download and include the class from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_get_html()

Comment: Whoops, please downoad the class.

Comment: You are right, now I don't have this error, but I have the resut (0) . I think that I have a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

You can use `domdocument` for this, or a number of other libraries. Here's a simple example:

```
$html = "
<p> answer 1 </p>   
<div class='right'>Obama</div>
<p> answer 2 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Brazil</div>
<p> answer 3 </p>
 <div class='right'>Tennis</div>
<p> answer 4 </p>
 <div class='wrong'>Sand</div>
<p> answer 5 </p>
 <div class='right'>Nike</div>";
$thedoc = new DOMDocument();
$thedoc->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $thedoc->getElementsByTagName('div');
$rights = 0;
foreach($divs as $div){
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'right'){
        $rights++;
    }
}
echo $rights;
```

Output:

```
3
```